# Field override for bdh() in pdblp

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi, pdblp

Bloomberg help isn't very helpful for their API. Can anyone please explain how to replace `PX_LAST` with the dividend adjusted price field. I have attempted the following but have been unsuccessful

```
import pdblp
con = pdblp.BCon()
con.start()

df2 = con.bdh(['NQ1 Index', 'DM1 Index'], ['PX_LAST'],
              '20061227', '20061231', elms=[("periodicityAdjustment", "ACTUAL")])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best place to look for this information is in the `BLOOMBERG OPEN API – REFERENCE SERVICES & SCHEMAS GUIDE`. To access this, from a Bloomberg Terminal go `WAPI <GO>` -> `API Developer's Guide`.

These are from page 20 `BLOOMBERG OPEN API – REFERENCE SERVICES & SCHEMAS GUIDE`

> adjustmentSplit {TRUE, FALSE}
>
> Adjust historical pricing and/or volume to reflect: Spin-Offs, Stock
>   Splits/Consolidations, Stock Dividend/Bonus, Rights Offerings/
>   Entitlement.
>
> adjustmentFollowDPDF {TRUE, FALSE}
>
> Setting to true follows the DPDF  BloombergProfessional service
>   function. True is default setting for this option

An example of this is showing Apple with and without the split adjustment incorporated is.

```
import pdblp

con = pdblp.BCon().start()

con.bdh("AAPL US Equity", "PX_LAST", "20140604", "20140610",
        elms=[("adjustmentSplit", True)])

ticker     AAPL US Equity
field             PX_LAST
date                     
2014-06-04        92.1171
2014-06-05        92.4786
2014-06-06        92.2243
2014-06-09        93.7000
2014-06-10        94.2500

con.bdh("AAPL US Equity", "PX_LAST", "20140604", "20140610",
        elms=[("adjustmentSplit", False)])

ticker     AAPL US Equity
field             PX_LAST
date                     
2014-06-04         644.82
2014-06-05         647.35
2014-06-06         645.57
2014-06-09          93.70
2014-06-10          94.25
```

Answer (score 2):

Can try out another wrapper library on top of `pdblp`: [`xbbg`](https://xbbg.readthedocs.io)

It’s possible to use same overrides as in Excel and use `kwargs` directly. Before any adjustments:

```
from xbbg import blp

blp.bdh(
    'AAPL US Equity', 'Px_Last', '20140604', '20140610',
    CshAdjNormal=False, CshAdjAbnormal=False, CapChg=False,
)
```

Output:

```
ticker     AAPL US Equity
field             Px_Last
date                     
2014-06-04         644.82
2014-06-05         647.35
2014-06-06         645.57
2014-06-09          93.70
2014-06-10          94.25
```

Adjust for splits:

```
blp.bdh(
    'AAPL US Equity', 'Px_Last', '20140604', '20140610',
    CshAdjNormal=True, CshAdjAbnormal=True, CapChg=True,
)
```

Output:

```
ticker     AAPL US Equity
field             Px_Last
date                     
2014-06-04          85.12
2014-06-05          85.45
2014-06-06          85.22
2014-06-09          86.58
2014-06-10          87.09
```

Comment: Can someone please let me know if you have tried something similar in Reuters?